# Decorate methods per instance in Python

Tags: python, decorator

Assume I have some simple class

```
class TestClass:
    def doSomething(self):
        print 'Did something'
```

I would like to decorate the `doSomething` method, for example to count the number of calls

```
class SimpleDecorator(object):
    def __init__(self,func):
        self.func=func
        self.count=0
    def __get__(self,obj,objtype=None):
        return MethodType(self,obj,objtype)
    def __call__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        self.count+=1
        return self.func(*args,**kwargs)
```

Now this counts the number of calls to the decorated method, however I would like to have per-instance counter, such that after

```
foo1=TestClass()
foo1.doSomething()
foo2=TestClass()
```

`foo1.doSomething.count` is 1 and `foo2.doSomething.count` is 0. From what I understand, this is not possible using decorators. Is there some way to achieve such behaviour?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Utilize the fact that `self` (i.e. the object which the method is invoked on) is passed as a parameter to the method:

```
import functools

def counted(method):
    @functools.wraps(method)
    def wrapped(obj, *args, **kwargs):
        if hasattr(obj, 'count'): 
            obj.count += 1
        else:
            obj.count = 1
        return method(obj, *args, **kwargs)
    return wrapped
```

In above code, we intercept the object as `obj` parameter of the decorated version of method. Usage of the decorator is pretty straightforward:

```
class Foo(object):
    @counted
    def do_something(self): pass
```

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't the first element of `*args` be the object the method is being invoked on? Can't you just store the count there?

Comment: Yes, I guess that would be possible. But it feels like suboptimal design to me as the decorator would rely on properties of the class it is used on making it harder to use.