# How do I decorate an instance method with another class in Python 2.7?

Tags: python, class, decorator, python-decorators, descriptor

In Python 2.7 I'd like to decorate an instance method `test` in class `Foo` with a decorator that is also a class called `FooTestDecorator`. From user Chirstop's [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6356858) and the Python 2 docs' [Descriptor HowTo guide](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html) I created this example.

There seems to be an issue however, when I print my decorated method object, it's (inspected?) name is wrong because it is noted as a question mark like `Foo.?`.

```
import types
class FooTestDecorator(object):
    def __init__(self,func):
        self.func=func
        self.count=0
        # tried self.func_name = func.func_name, but seemed to have no effect

    def __get__(self,obj,objtype=None):
        return types.MethodType(self,obj,objtype)
    def __call__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        self.count+=1
        return self.func(*args,**kwargs)

class Foo:
    @FooTestDecorator
    def test(self,a):
        print a
    def bar(self,b):
        print b
```

if you test it:

```
f=Foo()
print Foo.__dict__['test']
print Foo.test
print f.test
print Foo.__dict__['bar']
print Foo.bar
print f.bar
```

you get

```
<__main__.FooTestDecorator ...object...>
<unbound method Foo.?>
<bound method Foo.? of ...instance...>
<function bar at 0x...>
<unbound method Foo.bar>
<bound method Foo.bar of ...instance...>
```

You can see the replacement method is shown as `Foo.?`. This seems wrong.

**How do I get my class-decorated instance method right?**

note: My reason is that I want to use variables from the `FooDecorator` instance's `self` which I would set at init. I didn't put this in the example to keep it simpler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your decorator instance has no `__name__` attribute, so Python has to do with a question mark instead.

Use [`functools.update_wrapper()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.update_wrapper) to copy over the function name, plus a few other interesting special attributes (such as the docstring, the function module name and any custom attributes the function may have):

```
import types
from functools import update_wrapper

class FooTestDecorator(object):
    def __init__(self,func):
        self.func=func
        self.count=0
        update_wrapper(self, func)

    def __get__(self,obj,objtype=None):
        return types.MethodType(self,obj,objtype)
    def __call__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        self.count+=1
        return self.func(*args,**kwargs)
```

Demo:

```
>>> f=Foo()
>>> print Foo.__dict__['test']
<__main__.FooTestDecorator object at 0x11077e210>
>>> print Foo.test
<unbound method Foo.test>
>>> print f.test
<bound method Foo.test of <__main__.Foo instance at 0x11077a830>>
```

Comment: You type too fast. :(

Comment: @kojiro Actually, I believe that he has pre-answered all possible questions on SO, and the only reason he doesn't respond instantly is that it takes a while to locate the answers for copy-paste.

Comment: @SethMMorton really? I thought he had automated the search, too, and the only reason he takes so long is the Global Interpeter Lock.